# Navigation Link Runtime Error in building Countdown Timer

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

```
struct SlideFiveView: View {
    
    var time: Int
    
    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    private let width: Double = 250
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SlideOne()
            Text("\(vm.time)")
                .font(.system(size: 70, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                .padding()
                .frame(width: width)
                .background(.thinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 4))
                //.alert("Timer done!", isPresented: $vm.showingAlert)
        }
        
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button("Start") {
                vm.start(minutes: Float(time))
            }
        }
        
        
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            vm.updateCountdown()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting create a timer in a View Structure, where the variable, time is passed from a percious View and becomes the set value for the starting time, and a navigation link is being used to get to the above view, but a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b0bbfdc), error occurs and the app crashes when the navigation link is pressed.

Comment: you get the error when you press the navigation link, but you don't show the code for that. It seems to be relevant don't you think?